# Url Rewriting and security issues

Tags: security, url-rewriting

I'm developing a project in PHP which will use URL Rewriting, I was wondering if you have any particular advice in order to prevent security issues.

The main idea is to have just strings in the address

site/category

site/category/subcategory

site/category/subcategory/element

A second option that I was considering is having the numeric ID links to each string something like this

site/category-1

site/category-1/subcategory-35

site/category-1/subcategory-35/element-138

Thanks for the advice

Comment: URL paramaters are all passed as GET to PHP, so now you're using URL rewriting nothing has changed from a security perspective.

Comment: What is your concern?

Comment: I was thinking to check if the user change the address in the address bar and screw all the url rewriting. I thought it could be potentially dangerous for the web site. Is the worst case scenario a NOT FOUND page?